# enabling CONFIG_LIBIPW on kernel compiling

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I need to enable `CONFIG_LIBIPW=m` on kernel 3.4.0
[image]

I see that `IPW2100`, `IPW2200`, and `PCI` needs to be enabled, but I could not find any clue where they are on the `menuconfig`. I read on http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/LIBIPW.html that LIBIPW is defined at `drivers/net/wireless/ipw2x00/Kconfig`. Herebelow is the drivers/net/wireless on menuconfig, but there is no such ipw2x00 option. I enabled all possible options on the wireless menu, but nothing changes.

[image]

`.config` file does not have `CONFIG_LIBIPW`. if I add `CONFIG_LIBIPW` to .config manually, then do `make`, manually added lines are deleted.

Could anyone help me how I should enable the `CONFIG_LIBIPW`?

Comment: Look at the **Selected by:** line and make one of those conditions true.  It will then be automatically selected.  For instance, `IPW2100` and `PCI`.  Just type `/` followed by `IPW2100` to find them.  See [kconfig.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONFIG_LIBIPW` [is not a user-visible prompted symbol](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.wireless.general/63582) in `make menuconfig`. However, it'll automatically be selected if you enable `CONFIG_IPW2100` or `CONFIG_IPW2200` via `make menuconfig`.

Unfortunately, the options to enable `CONFIG_IPW2100` (*Intel PRO/Wireless 2100 Network Connection*) and `CONFIG_IPW2200` (*Intel PRO/Wireless 2100 Network Connection*) are missing in your screenshot. Typically, if you do not select all the required dependencies, the option will not appear in the menu.

You mentioned that you were not able to enable `CONFIG_PCI`. Since `CONFIG_PCI` is a required dependency of both `CONFIG_IPW2100` and `CONFIG_IPW2200`, you should make sure it's enabled. The prompt to enable `CONFIG_PCI` is: *Bus options (PCI etc.) --> PCI Support*.

Furthermore, verify that any other dependencies are enabled.

1. [`CONFIG_IPW2100`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IPW2100.html) requires:

   - `CONFIG_CFG80211`

     - *Networking Support --> Wireless --> **cfg80211 - wireless configuration API***
2. [`CONFIG_IPW2200`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IPW2200.html) requires:

   - `CONFIG_CFG80211`

     - *Networking Support --> Wireless --> **cfg80211 - wireless configuration API***
   - `CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT`

     - *Networking Support --> Wireless --> cfg80211 - wireless configuration API --> **cfg80211 wireless extensions compatibility***

*Note: while you can technically enable everything by hand via the `.config` file, you're likely to encounter [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) if you try.*